# Keeping console text with RedirectStandardOutput

Tags: c#, redirect, output

I'm creating a windows forms application and I'm trying to get the output from a console application whilst keeping the output printed out on the application aswell.

I tried creating a Process, setting RedirectStandardOutput to true and ExecuteShell to false, then I started an async read operation which worked perfectly, the problem is that my applcation "steals" the output from the application so the output isn't shown in the application anymore.

Is there any way to capture the output whilst keeping the output on the console application? I was thinking of perhaps capturing the output and then sending all of the ouput back to the outputstream of the application, but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance,

Jamey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native methods AllocConsole and FreeConsole can be used to create and destroy a console for any running process and child console processes will use their parent's console by default (they won't create additional floating console windows that aren't useful), so you can attach a console to your own process, start the child process, and then write the output to your newly allocated console to do what you're trying to accomplish. If you also need the user to be able to provide input to the console application, the solution will be somewhat hairier, but it should still be possible to put something together that starts a separate thread with the job of passing console input through to the child process. One other nice detail about this implementation is that you can keep the console and its output around past the exit of the child process if you want to.

The form below has two buttons, but to keep the example code compact I don't include the buttons themselves, just their click events.

```
public partial class RunForm : Form
{
    public RunForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void runButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NativeMethods.AllocConsole();

        using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c echo Hello world!";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            process.Start();
            process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        }
    }

    void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        // do other things with the output here
    }

    private void closeConsoleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NativeMethods.FreeConsole();
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool FreeConsole();
}
```